# Sliding images with Previous/Next buttons in javascript using animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slideshow of 4 banners with Prev and Next button. It works fine with the Prev button but not the Next button.My problem is Once I press the Next button, the images move not properly.

This is the result I need.=> The next image on the right slides from right to left when clicking Next button.Now it slides but sometimes some images slides back to the right.

Please help.Thank you

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/pktono/sr5nv6k9>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there was couple of issues to fix:

1- animation time was overriding the `css` command. To fix that, you should use `setTimeout` function where your aftermath code should reside inside of it.

2- When you navigate to right, you set the previous banner `left` property to -650px. If you decide to navigate to the left at this moment, you have a wrong `left` property which ruin the rules. The same thing can happen when you are navigating to left and want to switch to right. To fix this, you should change `left` property of the current banner to the right value before animating it.

See the working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zero_point/qeu506yg/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much.You save my life.I however have something to ask you about the setTimeout function that has "$("#banner" + prevbanner).css({"left": "-650px"});" . I don't think we need to have this line.When I tried to ignore this line. It is still working. Perhaps you might have a reason why you put it.

Comment: I also add  function rotateBanners() and have setIntervel of it.I updated all my code so that anyone who have the same issue as me can see it. click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pktono/sr5nv6k9/1). Thank you again Zero Point

Comment: @Pano: You are right. I think the `setTimeout` function is not needed altogether. I had it originally before recognizing the second issue that I described in my answer. You are welcome my friend.